# XSLT 1.0: replace new line character with _

Tags: xslt, exslt

I am having this below variable

```
  <xsl:variable name="testvar">
        d 
        e 
        d
    </xsl:variable>
```

and I have this function:

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($str-input)">
            <func:result select="false()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <func:result select="translate($str-input,$new-line,'_')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</func:function>
```

And when I tested the function I saw my result is like this:  **_ d _ e _ d_**
and I want my result to be only

**d _ e _ d**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:variable name="new-line" select="'&#10;'" />

  <xsl:variable name="str-input">
        d 
        e 
        d
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- your <xsl:choose>, slightly modified -->    
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($str-input)">
        <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="temp">
          <xsl:call-template name="normalize-newline">
            <xsl:with-param name="str" select="$str-input" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate($temp, $new-line, '_')" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>

  <!-- a template that trims leading and trailing newlines -->    
  <xsl:template name="normalize-newline">
    <xsl:param name="str" select="''" />

    <xsl:variable name="temp" select="concat($str, $new-line)" />
    <xsl:variable name="head" select="substring-before($temp, $new-line)" />
    <xsl:variable name="tail" select="substring-after($temp, $new-line)" />
    <xsl:variable name="hasHead" select="translate(normalize-space($head), ' ', '') != ''" />
    <xsl:variable name="hasTail" select="translate(normalize-space($tail), ' ', '') != ''" />

    <xsl:if test="$hasHead">
      <xsl:value-of select="$head" />
      <xsl:if test="$hasTail">
        <xsl:value-of select="$new-line" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$hasTail">
      <xsl:call-template name="normalize-newline">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="$tail" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

returns:

```
"        d _        e _        d"
```

The spaces are part the variable value. You could remove them using `normalize-space()`, but since I don't know what `"d"` or `"e"` is in reality I leave them unchanged.

Comment: @Tomalak

I have one question. you have only the variable:   
<xsl:variable name="new-line" select="'&#10;'" /> how about the carriage return "\r". 
I am not sure if there is are carriage return (\r) after d e d
<xsl:variable name="testvar">
        d\r\n or d\n\r 
        e\r\n or e\n\r
        d\r\n or d\n\r
    </xsl:variable>

Comment: Change `<xsl:variable name="new-line" select="'&#10;'" />` to whatever newline sequence you expect to show up in your values. For example, `select="'&#13;&#10;'"` would be okay as well.

Comment: Alternatively, you could do something like stripping any occurrence of `&#13;` using `translate($str, '&#13;', '')` - whatever measure you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your variable to:

```
<xsl:variable name="testvar">
        d 
        e 
        d</xsl:variable>
```

?

Comment: I can change it, but the function will not be flexible enough. also the contents of the variable will be read from an XML file not pre-assign.