# Check for CR or LF in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a input XML like this :

```
<in_xml>
 <company>
  <project>
    ProjNo1
    ProjNo2
    ProjNo3
  </project>
 </company>
</in_xml>
```

A simple XSLT is applied to this source, which writes another XML with the value of Project Tag.
The Project tag in input xml has three lines , it could be one or more line(s). I am looking at way for the XSLT to read only the first line, in case there are more than one and write the first line in the output xml.
The current XSLT is very simple as it just reads the Project tag and spits out the value, hence the code is not attached.

Regards.

I have added the answer to the question, see below @Maestro's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in the happy circumstances of being able to apply XSLT 2.0, the following may help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="//project/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(normalize-space(.),' ')[1]" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Explanation: first `normalize-space()` to replace all whitespace strings by a single blank (and cut off leading and trailing whitespace), then split into words, then take the first one.

In XSLT 1.0 you could use

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(normalize-space(.), ' ')"/>
```

instead. Less flexible if the second word has to be selected, but for the first word it works OK.

**EDIT**

you asked how to retrieve a first line in XSLT 1.0 - problem here is the leading whitespace which may contain a LF so you cannot just substring-before the first LF.
The below can probably be improved upon, but it works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="//project/text()">
        <xsl:variable name="afterLeadingWS"
select="substring-after(., substring-before(.,substring-before(normalize-space(.), ' ')))"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($afterLeadingWS, '&#xA;')">
                 <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($afterLeadingWS, '&#xA;')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                 <xsl:value-of select="$afterLeadingWS"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Explanation: first get first word as before, then determine the whitespace before that first word, then get everything after that leading whitespace, then get the first line, which is the string before a LF character. It may just happen that there is no LF except maybe in the leading whitespace, hence the choose function.

Comment: I guess the circumstances are not so favourable! Have to stick with XSLT 1.0 Appreciate your concern.

Comment: normalize-space() is present in XSLT 1.0 the code in this post shows it [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492736/xslt-1-0-replace-new-line-character-with), but I am not able to tweak it for my requirement.

Comment: then try <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(normalize-space(.), ' ')" />

Comment: Hi Maestro, first up thanks a lot for taking the time to help me out. I created the following XSLT: 'code' <xsl:template match="in_xml">
    <xsl:variable name="x" select="project"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="projText">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($x,'&#xa;'))">
          <xsl:value-of select="$x"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(normalize-space(project), ' ')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable> This outputs the only the first word of the first line!!!

Comment: The normalize-space method replaces even CR/LF with a space, hence it gives only the first letter of the first sentence.

Comment: @Codehelp actually it strips off whitespace (space, CR, LF, tab, vertical tab, formfeed) from start and end, and replaces any other sequence of two or more whitespace characters by a single space. substring-before(normalize-space(.), ' ') will thus return the very first string of non-whitespace characters.

Comment: So, (normalize-space(.), ' ') will not work as it returns the first string/word from the first line. Any other suggestions to get only the first line!!! Again, appreciate your help. If in the sample xml there is a line of text like 'Proj1 Test1', then can the XSLT return 'Proj1 Test1' and ignore the other two lines?

Comment: I am accepting the EDIT from @Maestro13. I like the way sub-string is nested and it helps a lot in maintaing the code, short and simple.

Answer (score 0):

first up thanks to @Maestro for taking time out and helping me, appreciate your help.
Here is the code that I used to get the first line from a paragraph of text that has a CR:

```
<xsl:variable name="projNumber" select="ProjectNumber" />
    <xsl:variable name="crlf" select="'&#10;'" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($projNumber,$crlf)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($projNumber,$crlf)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$projNumber"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

This can be written as a function but I don't know how to do it, maybe someone can guide but there you go. A better approach that a colleague of mine suggested is to escape the CR and directly use it in substring function this would avoid all those variables in the first place.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code again, now with a function getFirstLine.
Note the addtional namespace that is needed.
Also note that this does require XSLT 2.0 (xsl:function is not available in 1.0).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:f="http://temp.com/functions">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="//project/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="f:getFirstLine(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="f:getFirstLine">
        <xsl:param name="input"/>
        <xsl:variable name="afterLeadingWS" select="substring-after($input, substring-before($input,substring-before(normalize-space($input), ' ')))"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($afterLeadingWS, '&#xA;')">
                 <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($afterLeadingWS, '&#xA;')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                 <xsl:value-of select="$afterLeadingWS"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```